# Why can an ideal generated by a subset be written in this form?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I have a subset $F \subset R$ that generates an ideal $(F)$. Apparently this can be written in the form $$(F)=\{a_1f_1b_1+...+a_kf_kb_k|k \ge 0, f_i \in F, a_i,b_i\in R\}$$ or if $R$ is commutative then it can be written in the form $$(F)=\{a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k|k\ge 0, f_i \in F, a_i\in R\}$$
I can't see why this works or how it's the same. Can anyone briefly explain the reasoning behind this? Thanks.

Comment: $(F)$ is defined to be the smallest ideal that contains $F$. Call $B$ the right-hand side of those equalities. Show that $B$ is an ideal. It is clear that $F\subset B$. Now show that if $C$ is an ideal with $F\subset C$ one must also have all those elements of $B$ also inside $C$. So, $B$ is minimal among the ideal including $F$.